# Angular.js falha ao instanciar o modulo

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Bem, é a primeira vez na qual estou fazendo alguma coisa com o **Angular.js** e estou apanhando um pouco para criar uma mensagem de "Login e Senhas incorretos" com o mesmo.

Tenho um metodo em um arquivo .js que está abaixo:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('loginController', function($scope){
        $scope.displayLoginError = (url.indexOf("error") >= 0);
    });
```

Logo em minha .jsp fiz a importação do Angular e do arquivo com meu metodo:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/pages/login.js"></script>

Nesta mesma pagina tenho um form de login com a DIV que faz a verificação 

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="loginController">
        <div  ng-class="{{'': displayLoginError == true, 'none': displayLoginError == false}}">
            <span class="entypo-attention"></span> <strong>Erro!</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Login
            ou Senha Incorretos!
        </div>
    </div>
    <form class="form-signin" method="post"
        action="j_spring_security_check">

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon entypo-user"></span> <input
                name="j_username" id="j_username" type="text" class="form-control"
                placeholder="Usuario">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span style="padding: 0 14px;" class="input-group-addon entypo-lock"></span>
            <input name="j_password" id="j_password" type="password"
                class="form-control" placeholder="Senha">
        </div>

        <button type="submit"
            class="btn btn-lg btn-fltees btn-primary btn-block">Entrar</button>

        <a href="<c:url value="register"/>"
            class="btn btn-lg btn-fltees btn-primary btn-block">Crie uma nova
            Agência!</a>

    </form>
</div>
```

Bem, estou o usando o Spring Security. Logo quando a autenticação falha um parametro e adicionado na URL (...?error=403), pois assim meu método javascript pode entrar em ação e exibir ou não a mensagem no meu form.

O problema que tal mensagem de erro e exibida:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0-rc.1%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DmyApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20E

Alguem sabe como posso resolver?

---

EDIÇÃO

O método que realiza a verificação da URL. Na variável url o valor vem certinho.

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('loginController', function($scope, $location){
        var url = "" + $location.$$absUrl;
        $scope.displayLoginError = (url.indexOf("error") >= 0);
    });
```

Esse é o trecho no qual irá verificar se erro de autenticação e irá apresentar a mensagen informando:

```
<div ng-controller="loginController">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-class="{'': displayLoginError == true, 'none': displayLoginError == false}">
        <span class="entypo-attention"></span> <strong>Erro!</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Login ou Senha Incorretos!
    </div>
</div>
```

Mas a logica parece que não funciona e não apresenta mais erros no console do firebug

Comment: Não ta dando pra visualizar o erro completo por essa URL que tu passou. Tem como postar a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Segundo os códigos que você postou, o atributo `ng-app="myApp"` é definido duas vezes? `<html lang="pt-BR" id="ng-app" ng-app="myApp">` e `<div ng-app="myApp">`. Tirando essa última `div` não resolve o problema? De qualquer forma, poste o erro completo.

Comment: Olá @gabrielhof, bem eu retirei o `<div ng-app="myApp">` e não funcionou. Editei a pergunta com o erro completado que firebug me reporta. Obrigado

Comment: Parece ser um erro de sintaxe. Por que você colocou duas chaves (`{{`) no ngClass?
(`ng-class="{{'': displayLoginError == true, 'none': displayLoginError == false}}"`) Tenta colocar só uma em cada lado.

Comment: É verdade @Danguilherme. Acho que o a diretiva `ngClass` do Angular espera algo semelhante ao formato JSON: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Na verdade, é um objeto JSON que ela espera mesmo, porque ela vai tratar ele como um objeto javascript normal internamente.

Comment: Oi pessoal, acabei saindo de viagem e não pude testar a solução ofertado pelo nosso amigo @Danguilherme. Mas infelizmente não funcionou. A mensagem de erro desta vez foi outra. Está acusando que a **url**. Acabei pegando este exemplo em um blog, parece que não está correto a forma utilizada pelo redator do mesmo. Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como posso pegr o valor passado na URL? Atualizei a pergunta com o stacktrace recente. Obrigado a todos.

Comment: No arquivo login.js, na linha 3, você está referenciando uma variável `url` que não foi declarada anteriormente. Você pode postar o código desse arquivo pra confirmar?

Comment: Oi @Danguilherme, arrumei o problema da variavel **url**, masw agora parece que a logica não está batendo. Editei novamente a pergunta explicando o que ocorre. Obrigad pela ajuda.

Comment: Tu ta usando `ng-class` pra esconder a mensagem? Acho que não vai funcionar, remove esse `ng-class` e tenta usar `ng-show="displayLoginError"`.

Comment: Sim esse era o objetivo @gabrielhof. Funcionou perfeitamente com o **ng-show**. Obrigado pela ajuda. Vou pegar alguns links para aprender melhor sobre o Angular.js. Tem alguma sugestão que queira partilhar?

Comment: Legal :) ! Só lembra de postar uma resposta explicando o que tu faz pra funcionar.

Comment: Opa, já respondi da maneira que funcionou @gabrielhof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, pessoal a resolução do problema se deu pela edição do arquivo de .js onde se encontra o método no qual tem como objetivo mostrar ou não a mensagem de login.

**login.js**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('loginController', function($scope, $location){
        var url = "" + $location.$$absUrl;
        $scope.displayLoginError = (url.indexOf("error") >= 0);
    });
```

Esse é o trecho no qual irá verificar se erro de autenticação e irá apresentar a mensagem:

```
<div ng-controller="loginController">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="displayLoginError">
        <span class="entypo-attention"></span> <strong>Erro!</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Login ou Senha Incorretos!
    </div>
</div>
```

Lembrado que tive que alterar a tag  adicionando o parametro `ng-app="myApp"`